# How to arrange the x axis label in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-science

I have tried the following code with python

```
df1= df.groupby(['FCR','PRIORITY']) ['FCR'].count()  
df1.plot(kind='bar' , figsize = (15,7) )
```

but I'm not getting the desired output,  as per the image below

[image]

Comment: Please always provide a small reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `plt.xlabel("...", weight = '..', size = '...')`
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html

Comment: Or you have this kind of problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762486/how-to-add-the-second-line-of-labels-for-axes ?