# Adding a second label on the x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the specific labels that I would like to see on my bar chart.
To generate the plot, I am using the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

d = {'P': {0: 'BO', 1: 'BO', 2: 'BO', 3: 'BO', 4: 'BO'},
     'M': {0: 'NB', 1: 'LR', 2: 'SVM', 3: 'SGD', 4: 'RF'},
     'PP': {0: '0.72', 1: '0.71', 2: '0.85', 3: '0.54', 4: '0.75'},
     'R': {0: '0.82', 1: '0.62', 2: '0.64', 3: '0.54', 4: '0.70'},
     'F': {0: '0.71', 1: '0.52', 2: '0.76', 3: '0.73', 4: '0.65'},
     'A': {0: '0.91', 1: '0.91', 2: '0.92', 3: '0.92', 4: '0.92'},
     'D': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'B'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df2 = df.melt(['P', 'M', 'D'])
df2.value = df2.value.astype(float)
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df2,
    x='M',
    y='value',
    hue='P',
    col='variable',
    col_wrap=2,
    col_order = ['PP', 'R', 'F', 'A'],
    kind='bar',
    facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False},
    height=3,
)
```

The problem is that I would like to add D information on the dataset and it is not allowed to use style in that function. So I was thinking of adding a second label on the x-xis ('D') like in this example: [How to add the second line of labels for axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762486/how-to-add-the-second-line-of-labels-for-axes) .
However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error: ValueError: Could not interpret value `variable` for parameter `col`.

I would appreciate if you could help me to fix this error and visualise my data similarly using the code above, but with a second label on the x-axis for distinguishing bars by 'D'.

EDIT: df2 looks like as follows

[image]

Comment: Could you print what df2 looks like

Comment: I added an image to show how df2 looks like. I think the code should work fine to generate the dataset in the figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an attribute to column D for the x-axis tick marks. I'm getting the respective tick information from the subplot, processing it and updating it. This method can be applied even if the desired output is different.

```
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df2,
    x='M',
    y='value',
    hue='P',
    col='variable',
    col_wrap=2,
    col_order = ['PP', 'R', 'F', 'A'],
    kind='bar',
    facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False},
    height=3,
)
d_col = df['D'][:8]
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
    for i,l in enumerate(labels):
        tmp = l.get_text()
        labels[i] = tmp + '\n' + d_col[i]
        ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

[image]